# the UserID and Password control to log-in with c# and sql server

Tags: c#, sql

I started to use ADO.NET for 3 days and want to make a program that can control if UserID and Password is suited with it's database value or not .The point is that i am confused about control all UserID and Password rows to suitable.Must i control UserId and password one by one with a loop or is there any sql command to make this.Thanx..

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? Check if a username is taken or not?

Comment: *UserID and Password is suited with it's database value or not* care to expand your thoughts

Comment: BennyM,i want to control if it is true or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this to learn or for production use?

If it is for production use I strongly advice you to look into using the ASP.NET Membership provider instead of building your own security system. It is thoroughly tested and known to be secure.

If it is to learn then you should write a suitable SQL statement. One way to do it efficiently with one query is:

```
SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE UserId='GivenUserId' AND Password='GivenPassword'
```

That will give you one result row back if there is a successful match, or no row back if either user name or password is wrong.

Comment: i want to know the basics of that and also use.Now i have to make that program i talked about to end of the day.So can you explain how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I suggest to do not store password in DataBase in plain text, use simple [MD5 helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) to store MD5 hash of password and just compare hash instead of password itself

Comment: thanx for your suggestion,i google it and look like very helpful.No doubt i will use it soon(when i finished its basics.).Now i have to do it that way i explained.Because that is like a task(i'm a student and now i'm at internship,they wanted me to make it).